# Python regular expression quoted string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
str1 = "I am doing 'very well' for your info"
```

and I want to extract the part between the single quotes i.e. ***very well***

How am I supposed to set my regular expression?

I tried the following but obviously it will give wrong result

```
import re
pt = re.compile(r'\'*\'')
m = pt.findall(str1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to capture the group between the single quotes:

```
import re
str1 = "I am doing 'very well' for your info"
data = re.findall("'(.*?)'", str1)[0]
```

Output:

```
'very well'
```

Comment: Do you not need to print(data) in python? Does re.findall print results automatically?

Comment: @ChaseTaylor by convention on SO,  Python users do not generally include the `print` statement for reasons of code length.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve the problem with `re.findall`: find all sequences that begin and end with a quote, but do not contain a quote.

```
re.findall("'([^']*)'", str1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to place a word character and a space between the escaped single quotes.

```
import re
pt = re.compile(r"'([\w ]*'")
m = pt.findall(str1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is using regular expressions entirely necessary for your case? It often is but sometimes regular expressions just complicate simple string operations.

If not, you can use Python's native Split function to split the string into a list using `'` as the divider and access that part of the array it creates.

```
str1 = "I am doing 'very well' for your info"
str2 = str1.split("'")
print(str2[1]) # should print: very well
```

Comment: The string provided is a very simple example of what I want to achieve

Comment: You should have provided a more realistic example, then.

Comment: Then I suppose you will want to use regex's after all. I tried. :D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   import re
    pattern=r"'(\w.+)?'"
    str1 = "I am doing 'very well' for your info"
    print(re.findall(pattern,str1))
```

output:

```
['very well']
```